# Plotting a temperature vs months over 20 years with a data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, plot

I'm trying to plot multiple years of data with separate lines; months vs average temperature. I tried to make an example of the data frame im pulling from and the code I have so far. Everything I think of returns errors... I'm new to coding and python in general, only experience is with maltab. If you can explain why you are doing something it would help a ton.

```
temp = 
    Year    Jan Feb March   April   May ... Dec
0   2000... 50  50  60  70  80      ---      20
1   ...2020 50  50  60  70  80      ---      20



iterations = len(temp)
months = range(0,13)
for t in range(iterations):
    temp_row = temp.loc[t:t,'Jan':'Dec']
    display(temp_row)
    for k in temp_row:
        temp_curve = temp_row[k] 
        np.array(temp_curve)
        display(temp_curve)
        #plt.plot(months,temp_curve)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the sample code of what I will do with pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# generate dummy date like yours
temp = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,12)*30, columns=list('JFMAMJJASOND'), index=[2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005, 2006,2007,2008,2009, 20010])


for irow in temp.iterrows():
    irow[1].plot(label=str(irow[0]))

plt.legend(loc='best')
```

for your case, you will need to `set_index` your data to **Year**, then you can follow the post.

This is how my dummy data looks like.
print(temp)

```
              J          F          M          A          M  ...          A          S          O          N          D
2000  12.342590   9.260711   1.735357  21.824895  25.380114  ...   9.773481   4.792270  12.213138  27.748244  19.796061
2001  23.080735  15.683598   7.464897   4.183959  18.405491  ...  23.866642  14.599316  22.881472   7.615957  26.906499
2002  20.107562  17.852316  11.909449  21.699431  25.945887  ...  15.177818   5.772342  18.478828  24.078192  24.679237
2003  26.304684  22.789193  13.078816  22.902927  29.256451  ...  29.293733   2.419681  18.023879   3.959484  10.348911
2004   5.189235  26.834558   8.752410  19.501824   3.791169  ...  11.362553  19.649341   2.349020  26.256925  27.689834
2005  18.082067  29.943846  19.619793  14.655709   1.495455  ...  18.310192  23.027288  12.620621  10.606939  18.618919
2006  15.809287  28.932569  22.751014  20.373752  20.173283  ...   3.766981   1.975172  12.186322   9.732845   6.072891
2007  21.394103  26.702367   5.355906   8.520460  10.015972  ...  20.820766  24.173289  27.721310  18.718743   5.242733
2008   1.180471   4.700810   2.003914  16.746432  23.099671  ...   2.429412   0.318762   4.490221   4.873712  24.979399
2009   4.495193  24.272586  10.162848  15.666427  16.623729  ...  11.505728  19.955781  24.361377   6.816847   1.122686
```

[image]